# Compiling JUnit class at runtime in glassfish 3

Tags: java, maven, junit, glassfish-3, java-compiler-api

I have in my application JUnit tests to run, but these JUnit tests are created and compiled at runtime. I'm loading a text template, replace some class tags and want to compile this source code at runtime with the javax.tools.Compiler from java.

I'm deploying and running this application on a glassfish 3 and it seems to be the problem, that the compiler can't find the JUnit library (but it is included in the .war) and throwing compile exceptions. The created JUnit test source code would compile, there are no syntax errors or something like that.

The application is build via maven, here is the pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>de.phoenix</groupId>
<artifactId>WebService</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>WebService Jersey Webapp</name>
<build>
    <finalName>PhoenixWebService</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.16</version>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly2</artifactId>
        <version>${jersey-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.embedded</groupId>
        <artifactId>gf-embedded-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>de.phoenix</groupId>
        <artifactId>library</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.24</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<properties>
    <jersey-version>1.17.1</jersey-version>
    <hibernate-version>3.6.10.Final</hibernate-version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>glassfish.java.net</id>
        <name>GlassFish Maven Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/glassfish</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>m2.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Maven 2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>phoenixNexus</id>
        <name>Phoenix Maven 2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://meldanor.dyndns.org:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>m2.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Maven 2 Repository</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>phoenixNexus</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>http://meldanor.dyndns.org:8081/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
    </repository>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>phoenixNexus</id>
        <name>Internal Releases</name>
        <url>http://meldanor.dyndns.org:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
```

I'm using a little modified version of the CharSequenceCompiler (http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jcomp/) to compile the classes at runtime.
The compiler is working for source code using only jdk classes.

Any ideas?